# Running helm commands in a pod with istio-proxy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, istio

I am using istio-1.1.1. I have a pod which basically can run helm comands.
If I disable `istio-proxy`, I can easily run commands like

```
helm status --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '41683'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:41683"
```

The port number changes everytime.

However, when I enable `istio-proxy`, I get the following error:

```
# helm status --debug
Error: an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding (get pods)`
```

How can I debug this issue?
Does it have anything to do with egress?

Comment: Have you tried to inject Istio sidecar into `Tiller` Pod?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Helm client uses some random port for any attempt to connect to particular `Tiller` pod which is initially listening on port 44134, due to that fact I assume that any Helm client command enforce some port-forwarding, i.e `kubectl port-forward` from randomized port to the target port. Although, your `Tiller` Pod can be not included in Envoy proxy configuration(sidecar not injected), therefore Tiller Pod's container port remains not to be exposed to Istio `proxy-config`.

You may try to reach out some more information about debugging Envoy proxy via `istioctl` in official Istio [tutorial](https://istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/proxy-cmd/#deep-dive-into-envoy-configuration).